# I am unable to unlock home screen on Android Pie

Tags: lock-screens, home-screen, 9.0-pie

I've just updated my phone to Android Pie. While booting, I typed in my password PIN, and it unlocked to go to the home screen.

There when I type the same password, a "Wrong Password" error is being thrown. There is no "Forgot Password" option. How do I fix this with minimal damage?

Comment: didn't you configure another way to unlock screen? Face recognition, fingerprint, etc?